# Rust: access line in file by index, or is there another way to compare two lines

Tags: rust

i have a simple txt file with one value per line.
Is it somehow possible to compare two lines?

I was looking for a way to index each line and then compare the index [n] with index [n+1].
By now i am able to print each line, but not to compare the entries.

Here is my code:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::env;
use std::io::{self, BufReader, BufRead};


fn read_file(filename: &String) -> io::Result<()> {
    let file = File::open(filename)?;
    let content = BufReader::new(file);

    for line in content.lines() {
        println!("{}", line.unwrap());
    }

    Ok(())
}


fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let filename = &args[1];
    read_file(filename).expect("error reading file");
}
```

Comment: Is [`Itertools::dedup()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.1/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.dedup) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to collect all lines into a vector and use [`std::iter::zip` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.zip).

```
fn read_file(filename: &String) -> io::Result<()> {
    let file = File::open(filename)?;
    let content = BufReader::new(file);

    let lines: Vec<String> = content
        .lines()
        .map(|line| line.expect("Something went wrong"))
        .collect();
    
    for (current, next) in lines.iter().zip(lines.iter().skip(1)) {
        println!("{}, {}", current, next)
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

So for the input file having content,

```
1
2
3
4
```

`read_file` function will print

```
1, 2
2, 3
3, 4
```

Comment: thank you, that solved my problem!!